# WPF New Window with content

Tags: c#, wpf

I want create a new Window beside an existing main Windwoe with a scrollable Textbox.

I'm pressing in my main Window on a button "Open New Window" and then it should open a new Window with a scrollable Textbox.

inside `form2`

In WPF you can drag drop elements in the main Window but cant do that for a new window.
So I thought it is only possible when you create a new window in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

I was able to create a new Window trough:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs 
 {
    Form form2 = new Form();
    //Do intergreate TextBox with scrollbar in form2

    form2.Show();

 }
```

and now I want a Textbox

But how can I do that in C# or WPF?

Thx

Comment: Create the form in VS, just like you did with your main one. Then use your bit of code to open and display that form.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about WPF window and not a WinForms window?

Comment: @AndreiZubov: I'm guessing, but the click handler has the `RoutedEventArgs` parameter indicating that it is a WPF event handler. However, `form2` could be a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` indicating that Windows Forms perhaps by mistake has been mixed into the application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well... you can create a new Window and load into this Windows.Content a UserControl wich you createt in a new XAML.
Example:

```
NewXamlUserControl ui = new NewXamlUserControl();
MainWindow newWindow = new MainWindow();
newWindow.Content = ui;
newWindow.Show();
```

the Xaml is could be like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="Projekt"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       x:Name="newXamlUserControl"      
        Height="300" Width="300">

    <Grid>

        <TextBox Text = ..../>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a new WPF window in your project:

1. Project -> Add New Item -> Window (WPF)
2. Name the window appropriately (here I use `ConnectWindow.xaml`)
3. Add a `TextBox` to the XAML

   ```
   <Window
       x:Class="WpfApplication1.ConnectWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="Connect"
       Height="300"
       Width="300"
       ShowInTaskbar="False">
       <TextBox
           AcceptsReturn="True"
           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
   </Window>
   ```

   You can customize both `Window` and `TextBox` as you like.

There are several ways to display the window.

Displaying a modal window (`this` refers to the main window):

```
var window = new ConnectWindow { Owner = this };
window.ShowDialog();
// Execution only continues here after the window is closed.
```

Displaying a modeless child window:

```
var window = new ConnectWindow { Owner = this };
window.Show();
```

Displaying another top-level window:

```
var window = new ConnectWindow();
window.Show();
```