# Show new Window with New Data Content

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, csv

I have an application(more like a pop-up Window that is embedded within another application) that shows each student his/her grade for a course and it will ask them to rate that course. So basically a pop-up Window will show with the course and the grade and stars for rating. So for example if a student is taking three courses, three pop-up Windows should appear, each course with its respected course grade. And I am reading my data fron a csv file and  it's something like this:

```
Arthur, PE I, A
Jim, Calculus II, B+ 
Sara, Physics, A+ 
Arthur, Calculus II, A+ 
Paul, History, C 
Anne, Physics, B+ 
Anne, Intro to Algebra, A+ 
Jim, Chemistry, B+
```

So for example, Arthur should have two pop-up Windows; one for PE I and one for Calulus II. Anne should have two pop-up Windows as well and so on.

So in my code, I'm reading the csv file, looping over the entries in the file and assigning the columns to label contents (Where I am displaying the data) and I added an if statement, to see if the current student equals the student in the csv file to show only the data for that student. To test this, I am displaying the data in a message box(not on the main Window) so for Arthur, he's supposed to get two message boxes with each box containing data on his course and it's working and I was able to get two message boxes for Arthur. But my question is, if I want to display the data on the main Window and I want the main Window to pop-up with new data each time. So for example, Arthur gets a main Window and data on his PE I course and when he closes the window, he gets another new Window with data on his Calulus II course and so on.

Here's my code:

```
if (File.Exists(csvFile)) //checking to see if csv file exists
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile);

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] column = line.Split(',');

        if (student == column[0])
        {
            //this is not where i want to display my data, but to test
            // the concept, I am displaying the data in a messagebox
            MessageBox.Show(column[1] + " " + column[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to know how to display new data in a new Window just like how I am able to do this with the message box.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF New Window with content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213244/wpf-new-window-with-content)

Comment: tagged as Duplicate

Comment: Thanks for your response and I already checked the page you pointed me to, but the difference is, I don't want to launch a new Window from the main Window. I am trying to have the same Window with the same controls appear multiple times but each time with new data (as per the information in the csv file). So the main Window will appear at first and when the student closes the Window, if there's another entry for that student, the same Window will pop-up but with different data as per the csv file

Comment: Then just reopen it with new data bound to its content. Closing the MainWindow will close the Application so you should rethink your design. Mvvm is your friend.